# Re-initialize variable or declare new?

Tags: c#

In C#, is there a benefit or drawback to re-initializing a previously declared variable instead of declaring and initializing a new one?  (Ignoring thoughts on conciseness and human readability.)

For example, compare these two samples:

```
DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
col.ColumnName = "Subsite";
dataTable.Columns.Add(col);

col = new DataColumn(); // Re-use the "col" declaration.
col.ColumnName = "Library";
dataTable.Columns.Add(col);
```

vs

```
DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn();
col1.ColumnName = "Subsite";
gridDataTable.Columns.Add(col1);

DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn(); // Declare a new variable instead.
col2.ColumnName = "Library";
gridDataTable.Columns.Add(col2);
```

A similar example involving loops:

```
string str;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    str = "This is string #" + i.ToString(); // Re-initialize the "str" variable.
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

vs

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string str = "This is string #" + i.ToString(); // Declare a new "str" each iteration.
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

**Edit:** Thank you all for your answers so far.  After reading them, I thought I'd expand on my question a bit:

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

When I declare and initialize a reference type like a System.String, I have a pointer to that object, which exists on the stack, and the object's contents, which exist on the heap (only accessible through the pointer).

In the first looping example, it seems like we create only one pointer, "str", and we create 100 instances of the String class, each of which exists on the heap.  In my mind, as we iterate through the loop, we are merely changing the "str" pointer to point at a new instance of the String class each time.  Those "old" strings that no longer have a pointer to them will be garbage collected--although I'm not sure when that would occur.

In the second looping example, it seems like we create 100 pointers in addition to creating 100 instances of the String class.

I'm not sure what happens to items on the stack that are no longer needed, though.  I didn't think the garbage collector got rid of those items too; perhaps they are immediately removed from the stack as soon as you exit their scope?  Even if that's true, I'd think that creating only one pointer and updating what it points to is more efficient than creating 100 different pointers, each pointing to a unique instance.

I understand the "premature optimization is evil" argument, but I'm only trying to gain a deeper understanding of things, not optimize my programs to death.

Comment: "Ignoring thoughts on [...] human readability" -- ignoring the second most important factor (the first being "correctness") is probably a bad way to make a decision.

Comment: @Eric: I added that sentence only to dissuade answers like "do it this way; it's more readable".  Of course I consider making code readable paramount.  I was just looking for more technical answers, like if there was a performance difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second example has a much clearer answer, the second example is the better one.  The reason why is that the variable str is only used within the for block.  Declaring the variable outside the for block means that it's possible for another piece of code to incorrectly bind to this variable and hence cause bugs in your application.  You should declare all variables in the most specific scope possible to prevent accidental usage.

For the first sample I believe it's more a matter of preference.  For me, I chose to create a new variable because I believe each variable should have a single purpose.  If I am reusing variables it's usually a sign that I need to refactor my method.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds suspiciously like a question designed to provide information for premature optimization.  I doubt that either scenario is different in any way that matters in 99.9% of software.  The memory is being created and used either way.  The only difference is the variable references.

To find out if there is a benefit or drawback, you would need a situation where you really care about the size or the performance of the assembly.  If you can't meet the size requirements, then measure the assembly size differences between the two choices (although you're more likely to make gains in other areas).  If you can't meet the performance requirements, then use a profiler to see which part of your code is working too slowly.

Answer (score 1):

It is primarily a readability issue, whether you use the same declared name or not doesn't matter, since either way you are creating two separate objects. You really should create the objects or variables with a single focus in mind, it will make your life easier.

As for your second example, the only real difference in intialization is that by placing your string outside the scope of the "for" loop, you are leaving it exposed to more outside influences, which can be useful at times. There is no memory or speed benefit for declaring it inside or outside of the loop. Remember, anytime you make a change to a string variable, you are essentially creating a new string. So, for example:

```
string test = "new string";
test = "and now I am reusing the string";
```

is the same as creating two separate strings, like:

```
string test1 = "new string";
string test2 = "and now I am reusing the string";
```

To get around this, you would use the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(VS.71).aspx) class, which allows you to modify a string without creating a new string, and should be used in situations where a string will be heavily modified, especially inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the word "using" which destroy the object itself after the braces ends?
I am not sure but that's what I think. I'd like to know your opinions too.

For the second example, I use the second one always, I am not sure as well, but for example at some problems at the ACM-ICPC contest I used to have lost of bugs because forgetting to re-initialize, so I used this way.

Comment: That only applies to classes that implement IDiposable, not string or DataColumn.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, no, there should be no difference.  The main difference would be that local variables (in the case of classes, their "pointer") are stored on the stack and in your first case, if your function were for some reason recursive, having two local vars instead of one will cause you to run out of stack space faster in a deep-recursive function.  Getting close to that limit in either case would be a sign that you should probably use a non-recursive method.

Also, just to mention it, you could skip the variables altogether and write:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Subsite" });
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Library" });
```

Which I believe performance-wise will be like having 2 local variables, but I could be wrong there.  I cant remember exactly what that produces in IL code though.

Comment: Local variables are not _necessarily_ stored on the stack. The jitter is allowed to enregister locals if doing so is provably safe. Both the jitter and the C# compiler are also allowed to re-use stack slots for different variables if doing so is provably safe.